# Making a Mountain out of a Molehill

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

You are given a string of terrain, with molehills and mountains:

```
                        /\
                       /  \
              _/\__   /    \
          ___/     \_/      \_
____/\___/                    \___
```

Your job is to replace every molehill in the string with an equivalent mountain centered in the same column. The rest of the string must be unaffected. This may require additional lines at the beginning of the string.

A **molehill** consists of adjacent columns where the terrain goes up, immediately followed by adjacent columns where the terrain goes down. The shortest side must be exactly one column wide.

These are all molehills:

```
_____/\______

   /\________
__/

________/\
          \__

\           /
 \         /
  \       /
   \     /
    \/\_/
```

These are *not* molehills:

```
    /\
___/  \______

      ___
_____/   \___

____  _______
    \/
```

A **mountain** is like a molehill, but the shortest side is four lines high instead of one.

## Examples

```
                  /\
                 /  \
           ->   /    \
____/\____    _/      \_

                       /\
                      /  \
                     /    \
           __ ->    /      \__
_     /\__/      __/
 \___/

                         /\
                        /  \
               ->      /    \
  /\                /\/      \
_/  \__/\_____    _/          \_

_                _    _                _
 \              /      \      /\      /
  \            /        \    /  \    /
   \          /          \  /    \  /
    \        /     ->     \/      \/
     \      /
      \    /
       \/\/

                             /\      /\
                            /  \    /  \
                           /    \  /    \
_                     -> _/      \/      \
 \                                        \
  \                                        \
   \/\______/\_______                       \_

                        /\                           /\       /\
                       /  \               /\        /  \     /  \
              _/\__   /    \       ->    /  \      /    \   /    \
          ___/     \_/      \_          /    \  __/      \_/      \_
____/\___/                    \___    _/      \/                    \___
```

## Additional Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/75524) are forbidden.
- Input and output can be in any reasonable format.
- You may assume the presence or absence of trailing whitespace in the input string.
- There will always be enough space in the sides of the string as well as between molehills for any mountains you might need.
- If replacing the molehills with mountains creates additional molehills, you do not need to turn those molehills into mountains.
- The terrain cannot go both up and down in the same column. If this happens, the terrain does not move.
- If a particular column does not become part of a mountain, its height must remain unchanged.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: This is a nice challenge!

Comment: I think the second-last example should end with four \ and four _ and not seven \ and one _.

Comment: @ngm then the second molehill wouldn't be a mountain.

Comment: The challenge isn't quite well-defined then - we have to infer rules from the examples. You could turn the final molehill into a mountain with four or more \ and enough _ to end up with the same number of characters. The rule *the rest of the string must be unaffected* is not really defined.

Comment: Is your intention that *the first and last characters must not change vertical position* and also that *as few characters as possible should be changed*? This seems to be what the examples suggest, especially if the second last one is the only correct answer.

Comment: @ngm That's correct. Also, "the rest of the string must be unaffected" just means "don't change it where you don't need to".

Comment: It would be a good idea to edit the challenge specification to clarify these points.

Comment: Boy, that rule that ngm is inferring is pretty incomprehensible to me. Tempted to vote for 'Not clear what you are asking'.

Comment: In addition, the last rule "the terrain cannot go both up and down in the same column" - what does that mean? Surely "the terrain" is only one of three characters `/, \, _`, so how could it possibly go up and down at the same time?

Comment: @ChasBrown `Surely "the terrain" is only one of three characters /, \, _, so how could it possibly go up and down at the same time?` That's exactly **what** the rule means. It's supposed to clarify what happens when the terrain tries to do that, like in example 2.

Comment: Your new rule *If a particular column does not become part of a mountain, its height must remain unchanged* is not consistent with your 4th example. The trailing 4 characters vary in height in the output; but are all the same height in the input. Thus at least **some** of them have had their height changed. Also, still do not understand what the *cannot go both up and down* rule means. If you mean 'for any column not part of mountain-making, that column cannot be going down in the input and up in the output', well, that is happening in your third example.

Comment: And, to be clear, I like this challenge! Just trying to help you communicate what seems to be your requirements! Apologies if my comments are coming across otherwise.

Comment: @ChasBrown Which example? The last 4 characters don't move in the fourth example. As for the "cannot go both up and down" rule, that's not what it means. In the second example, the second column would have to turn into a `/` to preserve the height of the mountain, but it would have to stay as a `\` to preserve the height of the terrain to the left. This is where that rule comes in; it means that this sort of conflict becomes a `_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>509</s> <s>495</s> 480 bytes

```python
def f(S):
 B='\\';F='/';s=''.join(map(max,*S.split('\n')));t=list(re.sub(r'..((./\\[^\\])|([^/]/\\.))..',r'////\\\\\\\\',s));C=s.count;D=t.count;d=C(F)-D(F)+D(B)-C(B);m=[{'_':F,B:'_'},{'_':B,F:'_'}][d<0];d=abs(d);i=1
 while d:
	if s[i]!=t[i]:i+=7
	elif t[i]in m:d-=1;t[i]=m[t[i]]
	i+=1
 return'\n'.join(u for u in map(''.join,zip(*[u.ljust(2*len(S))for u in reduce(lambda (a,p),c:(a+[' '*[p,p-1][c==B]+c],p+[[0,-1][c==B],1][c==F]),t,([],len(t)))[0]]))[::-1]if u.strip())
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVZbj6M2FH6Of8Wp9sEwEJjsy1akbqXMaJ76lr1JwEYOOBt2CVBsOjO9/PbpMcZAZjJSVdVSbJ@Dz/3YX5pHdayrt09PuTjAwdm6EYENo0lC13eMhnQtGaXBt7qonBNv8PfgX20D2ZSFcmhSUdd114qVhVROKwLZ7Z2WBoHjBGGSxF@SJHX/cuIvYYpk4LpBQP2WhjiSYVBfooYbJoOs7iq1vmVq2OXsxrlzl7c4ebfOxl3e4LQ@sfhPuqPRnb@JcP3b76mNf9dTaZz/dJ2iKN9LJ3fXBVsRuD8WpYA8IoviADIu0h@YwjkqPPaOLESJXE0XFZyifMlWa02xU6yXFIU8raQVqmsrHbFJRgeHuoUOtBTmZciR/0fROFdxF5TfOszI26tSVJhTdzzbirzLhFPy0z7n4HC/cf0scrgXU6BXceM3y1UaZ4xtUi9L/caL42t/ZPlmc5e6vvKdOPW1eoUliK/TFOcowqMYThdI1aInrkuKU1O3Cu0@HUqulKjYYFtGz@tqfG8H37VqLE0fZqtdl/OqozU3aAcrhOjmEQ8Nr3KUwURLYP8@VN1sL6PtuUPA2IcYshxDliZksjBVgaks7eTvy7KoITQMtg8aVenuMzGqPsYxi4BpbKc09hEqgcJ9fArjG/LpHLQ7JmTLkkg3bVGpMSkeBWA/A1BP2W@EkO1W54lSusMRJnpGgpD3A5vANHY7sus3@lwIQECfD4evRmyU2@1mkqhFiyRGjdVppHu5D5O5MCFaZ2LdMf58HPXCs4HqknNO2Ns752jWnBcar2a8ECzL8kKYWIYXwpwFSZiEvXefXvXOHE8uci@xiVHbB24TMKTg84WSnMedvPZJ5/PZt165DWn@cSxpYkubYN2tN@El9Yl1kZC@Qbdb12ze29VuPgzrx2H9NKyfsb@1hl@FlFDvD53MuBI5ZHUuItP6h@lev4ADeQ4HCzve2PuAN0vVgE9OUX3Fl7gsKmGu0H9GDGugFU3JMwGnuhT4ypcS7gt1RBIBhBeVJIsczQzY4uAz4i7VjPBGAtW6SzmnrAneClBH/N3XoJ@D6qsE8VvHy/IR9rzkVSbyX8jC4hKq9bX8DJw06SN/hlBTik78u8DUYDIbVB0EAbo8Q6/FbLwB@b1ooP5dtFAKnuN5QJW9jMW48/OGKxVmBrrKetsLXMDCy5Z49QhZK7AhprSC885bMfYjPmUTfsIMQDHpKo6K1BtQ1MPZW0XpqB9lMl7Z@vmQ13avXQOPwbPQK/GgIDvy1nbO/wwuL/AUbTY8B9mgTxK4wpQfFLZwPvTu66g/hxdl4aVHf5W6U@vWCnN6AcJm/yzUhEUTpC@m5sf6SOyeKgctaa6Zvl0ymHDfXO2nfwA)

Still not clear what the actual rules are; but here are the additional constraints that are enforced above and beyond the rule that molehills shall be turned into mountains:

- The first and last terrain characters of the output must be `_`, just as they must be for valid inputs.
- The vertical difference between the first `_` and the last `_` must be maintained between the input and output.
- After substitutions from turning molehills into mountains, some other characters might need to be changed in order to maintain said vertical difference; but the characters changed must not be any of the characters that are part of mountains that were created from molehills.
- And when accomplishing these changes, the number of additional characters changed must be minimal.

#### Ungolfed Algorithm:

```python
def f(s):
    s = ''.join(map(max,*s.split('\n'))) # flatten into a single line
    t = re.sub(r'..((./\\[^\\])|([^/]/\\.))..',r'////\\\\\\\\',s) # replace molehills with mountains
    d = s.count('/')-t.count('/')+t.count('\\')-s.count('\\') # are the two strings equally balanced?
    m=[{'_':'/','\\':'_'},{'_':'\\','/':'_'}][d<0] # make an appropriate mapping...
    d=abs(d);i=1 # skip over leading '_'...
    while d: # while still unbalanced...
        if s[i]!=t[i]:i+=7 # skip over any created mountains (7+1==8)
        elif t[i] in m:d-=1;t = t[:i]+m[t[i]]+t[i+1:] # if can replace, do replace
        i += 1 # next char
    t = reduce(lambda (a,p),c:(a+[' '*[p,p-1][c=='\\']+c],p+[[0,-1][c=='\\'],1][c=='/']),t,([],len(t)))[0]  # pad spaces at left side
    t = map(''.join,zip(*[u.ljust(max(map(len,t))) for u in t])) # rotate
    return '\n'.join(u for u in t[::-1] if u.strip()) # reverse and join into lines.
import re
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>855, 845</strike> 833 bytes

```
func[s][r: split s"^/"c: charset"\_/"m: copy #()repeat n l: length? r[parse r/:n[any[i:
c(put m 1 + offset? r/:n i reduce[first i n])| skip]]]m: extract next sort/skip to-block m
2 2 e: copy[]parse b: rejoin collect[foreach c m[keep c/1]][any[c:["/\_"|"/\/"](alter
e 1 + offset? b c)| c:["_/\"|"\/\"](alter e 2 + offset? b c)| skip]]y: 0 foreach a e[q: p:
d: -3 + min m/(a - 4)/2 m/(a + 5)/2 if d < y[y: d]j: i: a until[m/:i/1: #"/"m/:i/2: p k: i
- 2 if all[k > 0 #"_"= m/:k/1 p = m/:k/2][m/(k + 1)/1: #"_"m/(k + 1)/2: p break]i: i - 1
m/:i/2 < p: p + 1]j: j + 1 until[m/:j/1: #"\"m/:j/2: q k: i + 2 if all[#"_"= m/:k/1
p = m/:k/2][m/(k - 1)/1: #"_"m/(k - 1)/2: p break]j: j + 1 m/:j/2 < q: q + 1]]y: y - 1 q:
collect[loop l - y[k: copy""keep pad k p: length? m]]repeat n p[w: m/1/2 - y
q/:w/:n: m/1/1 m: next m]foreach d q[print d]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZLPjtsgEMbvPMWIXBKtIuq0vaC2@w69ArUcjBvH/wgm2lrdPns6GNubTbI@2MPMx3w/DziTX36aXChS8EtxbrXolXAceluXHnr6i1HNQR8y1xtPZcpog8vODrBab5yxJvPQQs2hNu1vf3gGJ2zQgmO8FVk7iJITvbZnDw0k8ARdUWCn57EOJTiTn7URRel6j8tWbV6hr0qrlEIj88e7TKMDBtB3zrNQA99t93WnK2jIDnZgIpFQ0XnPseuxK1vM1rXRXhSdM5k@gIZGVMZY0CxRaqTTXFAmU/qKb0bVOqu9ccS8Q92DRqqgTJlEpcT3pASD/rfKyD9w@ASzcwZGnDhYTnIO28@4pUG@hq0z2MKXDdvF@Am@hrgsIIdvMAjskasjh5Jjh3Pry1o0jJcs4bCieBQh3mFbqFBDtjBuzepaVPAD3Vc0pd@xM69YgqIp3Clssq7QLNnETil9S4zt9khdKXQtES8h0QeJbCiiLDAdQ/AGdYytJB1j7HIaoVC0QF3jkDuc7S3O9gZn8YwOiHMKLgEnDHsIGzBF5lOvu85CjdlBVPGGUDqevs1yqMK/zHe2UWq5yla8cHRI0AB3khPjL3hTYwqtebyLjZpPNoeTsK5sPZ6UuhTwN8UHbxQ@/wjBNQCTJGUAcs6nBCux9PhhcvyQj8rYawpvJKNBVCyaK0kgGwM5fTEYJQsze@Qnr5DTh0RkAbqvfFQKXHIayDyYh6PBZDqNZQYkIxNbxPJuQHfG7Nr2Ph3HJG/ScXZTlk2TlNeL8AuB4/If)

Far, far away from a golfy solution...
It passes the test cases but most probably would fail on some other, more strange pattern.

### More readable:

```
f: func [ s ] [
    r: split s "^/"
    c: charset "\_/"
    m: copy #()
    repeat n l: length? r[
        parse r/:n[ any [ i: c(put m 1 + offset? r/:n i reduce[ first i n ])
        | skip]]
    ]
    m: sort/skip to-block m 2
    m: extract next m 2
    b: rejoin collect [ foreach c m [ keep c/1 ] ]
    e: copy []
    parse b [ any [ c: [ "/\_" | "/\/" ]
                (alter e 1 + offset? b c)
            | c: [ "_/\" | "\/\" ]
                (alter e 2 + offset? b c)
            | skip
        ]
    ]
    y: 0
    foreach a e [
        q: p: d: -3 + min m/(a - 4)/2 m/(a + 5)/2
        if d < y [ y: d ]
        j: i: a
        until [
            m/:i/1: #"/"
            m/:i/2: p
            k: i - 2
            if all [ k > 0
                     #"_" = m/:k/1
                     p = m/:k/2
            ] [ 
                m/(k + 1)/1: #"_"
                m/(k + 1)/2: p
                break
            ]
            i: i - 1
            p: p + 1 
            m/:i/2 < p
        ]
        j: j + 1
        until[
            m/:j/1: #"\"
            m/:j/2: q
            k: i + 2
            if all [ #"_" = m/:k/1 
                     p = m/:k/2
            ] [
                m/(k - 1)/1: #"_"
                m/(k - 1)/2: p
                break
            ]
            j: j + 1
            q: q + 1 
            m/:j/2 < q
        ]
    ]
    y: y - 1
    q: collect [
        loop l - y [
            k: copy ""
            keep pad k p: length? m
        ]
    ]
    repeat n p [ w: m/1/2 - y
                 q/:w/:n: m/1/1
                 m: next m ]
    foreach d q [ print d ]
]
```